# Should I use return keyword when rendering a view?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm not sure if that's so important but I like clean code so here's my question :

I use node.js with express. I have declared routes that render views :

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    return res.render("index.jade");
});
```

Can I remove the "return" keyword like this :

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
   res.render("index.jade");
});
```

I've found lots of examples with both syntax. Don't know which one to use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your case it doesn't matter at all. However using return is a common method when using conditionals. For example:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
  if(req.whatever) {
    // Using return here will cause any code after to not be run
    return res.render("index.jade");
  }

  // Default action
  res.render("default.jade");
});
```

Comment: you mean : with your example, if I don't use return, the second render would be called ?

Comment: @BenjaminSimon yes exactly

Comment: A more detailed explanation of this coding rule is given on http://stella.laurenzo.org/2011/03/bulletproof-node-js-coding/ under the topic "1. Return on the Last Statement"

Comment: So should we conclude that a good way to never make mistakes (which is what clean code should lead to) is to ALWAYS place a "return" keyword when rendering a view (or res.redirect or res.send ...) ?

Comment: @BenjaminSimon Sure in the general case you might choose to always do so, but personally I won't. It's just a matter of preference, and there might be cases where you want to do something after the response is sent, which a `return` won't allow. (don't forget to accept if this answer helped you)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using or switching to ES6+, this can be shortened using arrow functions to:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => res.render("index.jade"))
```

which adds an implicit return statement, whilst keeping the code clean.

The example in the correct answer above can also be rewritten as:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => return req.whatever ? res.render("index.jade") : res.render("default.jade"))
```